# Heavy Shadows On meshes

Tags: rendering, mesh, shadows, normal-map

I am trying to build a game in UE4, and when working on my wall mesh stumbled upon heavy shadow problems. When creating a low poly mesh from a high poly mesh with cage be baking normal map and AO.

[image]

As can be seen in this picture the player have a light source so there should not be any shadows there at all (Ignore the missing UV there).
As well there should not be a crack of shadow between the meshes of the wall.

[image]

I am getting really desperate just fixed another problem with even more heavy shadows but now I am stuck.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hello. Hard to see here if it is a Blender problem or something to tune in UE... How does it look like in Blender with the same kind of lighting ?

Comment: Hi. Would you mind uploading the file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and post the link here?

Comment: @metaphor_set Here is the links :http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1679/
http://i.stack.imgur.com/3CrZj.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/ipPGW.png

Comment: @lemon No I don't think that the problem is in ue4 because when I enter the high poly mesh its works cool and dandy,

Comment: There is non manifold parts and inverted normals. But, I don't know how UE reacts to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea in the end it was normal map problems, no clue why the hell the normal map from cage does not work at all but I just baked normal map form high and low poly mesh, and that fixed most of the shadow problems(after I flipped the green in the texture in UE4), took me whole 3 days to fix this god dammit, but at least I know how to bake normals now -_-... 
Thanks for trying to help me.